# Creating A New Visualization in Elastic Kibana on only a portion of a message

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to create a data table based on the unique count of CC addresses: Unfortunately the message contains a unique transaction id preventing me from getting a unique count.

Example:

message: "123456689101112131415161718 : Pre-Dispatcher : CC Info: Loc 534 - CC sample-CC@email.com"

I need to build a table on unique counts of only the data after "CC Info"

Any tips on how I can accomplish this?

I tried searching using a regular expression but it produce no results
"regex(message.keyword, '\d*\s*:\s*Pre-Dispatcher : CC Info:/s*(.*)')"

Comment: Not sure if it works, but the last one should also be `\s` like `\d*\s*:\s*Pre-Dispatcher : CC Info:\s*(.*)`